# confused with the definition of the limit point

Tags: real-analysis

Let p be a limit point of k. by definition of limit point, for each n$\in N$ there exist
$P_n \in K $ with $P_n \ne p $ such that

$$|p_n - p| < 1/n $$

I do not understand the part  1/n. why they choose this 1/n thing?

Comment: Because it tends to zero when $n$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: There are other way to write this definition?

Comment: In English: "whatever neighborhood of $p$ we consider, we can always find a point of $K$ which is distinct from $p$ within this neighborhood (in particular: as close to $p$ as needed)" This can also be formulated with $\epsilon-\delta$'s.

Answer (score 0):

[-------------------------------------------------

0  $\hspace{2cm}$                $ 1/n_\epsilon \hspace{0.5cm} \epsilon$

As $ 1/n \rightarrow 0 $, given any $\epsilon > 0$ we have a corresponding $n_\epsilon \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $1/n_\epsilon < \epsilon $  And :

$$ |p_{n} - p| < 1/n < 1/{n_\epsilon} < \epsilon. $$ for all $n > n_\epsilon$.

So indeed the sequence $p_n$ converges to $p$. And roughly to show something is a limit point in metric spaces (spaces with notion of distance here |.|), we need to find a seq in the set converging to the point p except for constant tail (i.e. $p_n = p$ for all $ n > n_0$).

Hope that helps.